# Does spark uncompresses the data for processing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a input data stored in csv format, compressed as .gz files on gcs/s3.

When spark reads the data for processing, does it uncompress the data to memory before processing? If spark uncompresses the data, so to configure the right cluster size, do we also need to consider overall uncompressed data volume?

Comment: Yes -- data is uncompressed once read in and you need to consider the size given this decompression.

Comment: csv.gz is a really bad format. gz doesn't support splitting: only one worker can process it. .csv is just, well, bad. And inefficient. read once, save as avro or parquet and you'll benefit in space and performance